# Textfield autosize with cdata html text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i want to be able to change the width and height of multiline textfield, according to textfield's dynamic data. Height is not the problem but width doesn't change. Width has to be resize automatically just like single line textfield. Is there a way to do this?

i have a xml data like this:

```
<![CDATA[<b>some long text</b> <br> some long text <br> some long text ]]>
```

in actionscript:

```
tx_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tx_txt.htmlText = fromXML;
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739154/as3-maximum-textfields-width/10739333#10739333

Comment: that is not i was looking for. i want the width to be automatically resizable. i edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to set `multiline` to true and omit the `width` property and the field should adjust to the length of the longest line before breaking:

```
import flash.text.*;

var fromXML:String = "<b>some long text adfs afdsadfs afdsadfsfads</b> <br> some long text <br> some long text";

var tx_txt:TextField = new TextField();
tx_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tx_txt.multiline = true;
tx_txt.htmlText = fromXML;
tx_txt.border = true;

this.addChild(tx_txt);
```

Comment: this is not i was looking for. i want width automatically resizable.

Comment: So using the string in your example code above, should the width of the textfield be display the longest line without a break?

Comment: yes, width should be automatic. Single line textfield works if you make it autosize="true". But multiline field does not work that way.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, this works. But i don't understand the difference. I think i have to create textfields by code. it happened before.

Comment: I've worked with Flash for about 10 years and, honestly, I don't think I've ever fully understood the relationships between the various properties of TextField. My strategy tends to be to play around until I get a combination which works.

Comment: adobe was saying they will build a new text class which better than this.

Comment: I think you're talking about the Text Layout Framework: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/tlf/home/Home/.

Comment: yes i am. they were building something new. TLF is not used by the comminity, they were planning something new.